# How to extract chemical terms using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to extract chemical terms using regex in Python. For example, given the following input string, I need to extract the output:

input string:

```
"the common composition consists of 3,4,5-trihydroxybenzaldehyde and 4-(1-imidazolyl)benzaldehyde, and mixture thereof."
```

output list:

```
['the', 'common', 'composition', 'consists', 'of', '3,4,5-trihydroxybenzaldehyde', '4-(1-imidazolyl)benzaldehyde', 'and', 'mixture', 'thereof']
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you try and in which way did it not satisfy you?

Comment: looks like you just need `Your_string.split()`?

Answer (score 0):

We'd likely want a more sophisticated expression than:

```
\b[a-z0-9-,)(]+\b
```

However, our desired output might be returned here in this specific example.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4OXISn/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\b[a-z0-9-,)(]+\b"

test_str = "the common composition consists of 3,4,5-trihydroxybenzaldehyde and 4-(1-imidazolyl)benzaldehyde, and mixture thereof."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks a simple and great answer. I've also found that the following regex (regex=r"[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z])|[\,\w\-\(\)]+") can also work well on more complex strings such as - "3'-O-(3-(N-(4-azido-2-nitrophenyl)amino)propionyl)adenosine-5'-triphosphate."